# OpenLayers Google Closure externs file

Tags: openlayers-2

Has someone written Google Closure Externs file for OpenLayers that I can use freely ?

Externs file similar to those for [jQuery, GoogleMaps, Underscore](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/trunk/contrib/externs#externs)  ?

Have to ask this before I create my own if none is available.